# I want to create a C# Script that creates a random infinite map for my grappling game

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I made a 2D Grappling Game in which the player is supposed to travel through the map by grappling from object to object. Right now I just dragged some of those prefabs into my scene in order to try out the gameplay. I also have some power-ups and obstacles. However, I want the map to be infinite on the x-axis. To achieve that I want to randomly instantiate my map prefabs when the player or better the cameras bounds move. Also I want the script to work with different probabilities and random spawn positions for the map prefabs.
I am not really sure how to approach this as I don't know whether it would make sense to use some sort of randomly generated chunks that get instantiated or something else.

The only scripting I have done for now is this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 screenBounds;

    [Header("Map Prefabs:")]
    public GameObject Rec;
    public GameObject Circle;
    public GameObject Coin;
    public GameObject Thorn;
    public GameObject Time;
    public GameObject Boost;
    public GameObject Multi;
    public GameObject Disabler;

    void Start()
    {
        screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    }


}
```

[SceneView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7tn8.png)

[Game Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pS8F.png)

Comment: Question is very broad. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome. I answered with a possible algorithm. I think your question is a bit too broad to include all the needed code. Hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach depends a lot on what exactly you want. Here's the first option that came to my mind.

1. Start by generating the middle rectangle and all rectangles around it
2. When the camera center goes beyond one of the edges, generate new rectangles so that the map around your camera is always generated. For instance, if your camera goes to rectangle (1,0), generate (2, -1), (2, 0) and (2, 1)

[image]

Generating a rectangle:

1. Generate as many map elements as you want to have on that rectangle.
2. Randomize their positions within that rectangle.